# Is the deduction theorem true in natural deductive systems?

Tags: logic

My native language is Chinese, so I use a translation machine.
In natural deductive systems, conditional proofs are called deductive theorems. But why does the condition proofs true? 
For example:
$R\vdash P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow P)$ does not hold in natural deductive systems, but we can prove $R,{P}\vdash Q \rightarrow P$, at this time, according to the conditional proof, we'd say it's tantamount to proving $R\vdash  P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow P)$. Why is that?
In the Axiom system, If we prove $R,{P}\vdash Q \rightarrow P$, according to the deductive theorem, we can derive step by step $R\vdash P \rightarrow (Q \rightarrow P)$, but it doesn't work in the natural deduction system. Why?

Comment: Why do you say $R\vdash P\rightarrow(Q\rightarrow P)$ doesn't hold in natural deduction? In natural deduction,  $P\rightarrow(Q\rightarrow P)$ is usually not taken as an *axiom*, but it is provable.

Comment: It depends on exactly what rules are defined for the system you are interested in, but as long as the rules are complete, the Deduction theorem holds.

Comment: How to prove R⊢P→(Q→P) by direct proof? We cannot give a constructive proof of  R⊢P→(Q→P)without using conditional proof.

Comment: Detailed instructions are in symbolic logic written by I.M. Copi.

Comment: In the usual logical system referred to as natural deduction $P \to (Q \to P)$ is provable. The proof is represented by the $\lambda$-term $\lambda p\lambda q.p$. If you are having problems with the book by Copi, please explain in more details what those problems are.

Comment: In the natural deduction systems that I've seen, the deduction theorem is built in, as a basic rule of inference, usually called implication introduction.

Comment: I.M. Copi said, “The nineteen Rules of Inference presented thus far are incomplete, which is to say that there are truth functionally valid arguments whose validity cannot be proved using only those nineteen Rules.” So I.M. Copi used a new rule called the conditional proof. I don't understand why we can use conditional proof？

Comment: In an axiomatic system, deductive theorems can be proved. But in natural deduction systems, none of us have proofs for conditional proofs. Many people are directly using condition proof.

Comment: IN ND the Deduction Theorem is simply [Conditional Introduction rule](https://iep.utm.edu/natural-deduction/#H4).

Comment: I know that in axiomatic systems, deductive theorems can be proved by mathematical induction. Whereas in the natural deduction system, the deduction theorem is regarded as a rule of inference, so we can use the deduction theorem directly without using mathematical induction to prove the deduction theorem, right?

Comment: There are *rules of inference*: MP in axiomatic presentation of logic and many rules (like Conditional Intro and Elim) in systems like Natural Deduction. In the first case, we can prove a result **about** the system, called Deduction Theorem, asserting that: having a deduction of $Q \to P$ from $P$ (this is the meaning of $P \vdash Q \to P$) we can produce a new deduction of $P \to (Q \to P)$. This result is not a rule of the system (there is only one: MP) but a so-called meta-theorem.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA In the textbook you sent me, it does treat deduction theorems as rules of inference in a natural deductive system, without giving a proof of the deduction theorem.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA https://iep.utm.edu/natural-deduction/#H4

Comment: As said, there is **no** Deduction Th in Natural Deduction, because it is "built in" into the $(\to \text I)$ rule: "from derivation $\Gamma, P \vdash Q$, we construct the new derivation $\Gamma \vdash P \to Q$".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA As far as I know, there are three different systems in the natural deduction system, namely "Copi-style proofs", "Lemmon-style proofs" and "Gentzen-style proofs".  I have only studied "Copi-style proofs", in "Copi-style proofs", there are usually 19 rules of inference, and a proof method called "conditional proof", "conditional proof" is very similar to "  (→I) rule" you said, in the natural deduction system, are they the same?

Comment: Yes, they are....

Comment: I see, thank you.